# Access violation writing location 0x00000000 Error in C++

Tags: arrays, pointers

I've been trying to implement a library system code. However, whenever I try to pass my object to array I get

> Access violation writing location 0x00000000

error in Visual Studio 2013

Here is my code
LibrarySystem.cpp

```
static int bookSize = 0;
static int studentSize = 0;

LibrarySystem::LibrarySystem()
{
    books = NULL;
    students = NULL;
}
LibrarySystem::~LibrarySystem()
{
}

void LibrarySystem::addBook(const int bookId, const string name, const string authors, const int year){
    bool checkBook = false; //checks whether the book is in the list

    Book *tempBooks = new Book[bookSize++];

    Book newBook;
    if (bookSize == 1) {
        newBook.setBookId(bookId);
        newBook.setBookName(name);
        newBook.setAuthors(authors);
        newBook.setYear(year);
    }
    tempBooks[bookSize - 1] = newBook;
    cout << tempBooks[1].getAuthors(); // To testing. This is where execution stops
    }
}
```

Comment: `tempBooks[1]` is probably not initialized to anything at this point. Maybe you meant `tempBooks[0]`?

Comment: It didn't work. There is still that error

Comment: I wanted to increment the size of tempBook array whenever the function called

Comment: You are create a _new_ array every time the function is called - if you want to increment to size of the array then I suggest you learn about std::vector - collections have been designed for those who have a poor understanding of pointers.

Comment: but tempBook is a local variable. What you have doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @LeonardoHerrera I agree - I'm very puzzled a student wants to learn advanced concepts such as objects - before gaining even a basic understanding of pointers - it beggars belief, really.

Comment: Please take the time to write a minimal code sample, that is: Remove unneeded code (What's a LibrarySystem?) until only the code that causes the array remains. For example, I reduced your code to this: http://pastebin.com/wUC4K0mv for testing it. Often, you'll find the error in the process of reducing it.

Answer (score 1):

C (and C++) arrays indexes are zero based.

```
cout << tempBooks[0].getAuthors();
```

**Edit**: Also, [as others have pointed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22769375/7841), `new Book[bookSize++]` looks suspicious.

Answer (score 1):

Your array is created to have 0 entries by

```
Book *tempBooks = new Book[bookSize++];
```

`bookSize++` will evaluate to the current value of `bookSize`, which is 0.

If you want to evaluate to the value after incrementation, use `++bookSize`.

Comment: @BurakKantarcı - A word of caution: that looks like it's working, but it is not. Your `tempBook` array is a local variable that doesn't get changed but created over and over again with a different size.

Comment: @LeonardoHerrera I'm going to add them on another array which _books_ will point. This will be the next step of my coding

Comment: @LeonardoHerrera: Indeed. In addition, it produces a memory leak. In C++, you'll want to use `std::vector` to take care of memory management for you.

Comment: @mic_e this is a class project and I'm forbidden to use vector class unfortunately.

Comment: @BurakKantarcı - if this is a class project the more reasons to get to a minimal working example, with `main()` included so people will be inclined to copy and paste your code and tinker with it. You'll get much better answers once you start doing that. Avoid posting questions where we have to resort to psychic debugging!